# Converting a result of Integer to String or Word in C

Tags: c

so i have a problem here. I am working on my class assignment which is create a calculator but every result must be in a word, example :

```
int a,b,c;
printf("Input first number:");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("Input second number:"):
scanf("%d", &b);
c=a+b;
printf("The result are: %d", c);                          
printf("If in words, it is  = ");
switch(c){
case 0:printf("abcdef");break;
case 1:printf("bc");break;
case 2:printf("abged");break;
case 3:printf("abgcd");break;
case 4:printf("fbgc");break;
case 5:printf("afgod");break;
case 6:printf("fgcde");break;
case 7:printf("abc");break;
case 8:printf("abcdefg");break;
case 9:printf("abcdfg");break;
default :printf("error");break;
```

So the result from this when im running it is :

> Input first number : 12
>
> input second number : 12
>
> The result are: 24
>
> If in words, it is = error

so what I'm confused here is how I did print the c result as a word? so what i want from my output is

> Input first number : 12
>
> input second number : 12
>
> The result are : 24
>
> If in words, it is = abged fbcg

so far I'm searching for answers but I cannot find it. If anyone here can help me, please do.

Thanks in advance

*edited

Comment: What exactly is your question ? There's no _out-of-the-box_ solution to convert numbers of words ...

Comment: `The result are`... ___are___?

Comment: You can declare a function that take "Number Type" and return desired "String" for you. and you can use this function in printf() statement. But I don't understood your question clearly

Comment: Don't know what the question is, but no `break` on any `case` can't be right...

Comment: i forgot about break; in every end of each cases there. also my question is about how do i print those words like abcdef from the result of c calculation (refers to c=a+b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what i want from my output is
>
> ```
> Input first number : 12
>
> input second number : 12
>
> The result are : 24
>
> If in words, it is = abged fbcg
> ```

The question would be much clearer if you had written "two four" instead of "abged fbcg"...

You apparently want to print the "tens" and the "ones" separately. (Probably the  "hundreds" as well.)

**As this is a homework assignment, I will only give you some hints instead of a complete solution**:

- If you divide `c` by 10, you get the "tens". If you divide that result by 10 again, you get the "hundreds".
- If something like "two four" would be acceptable, you can use the same lookup for "tens" and "ones". If you actually need "twenty four", you need a lookup for "tens" and a different one for "ones".
- You need to print the words for the highest-order (leftmost) digit *first*, but you get it *last* from the by-10 divisions I mentioned above. So you need to "store" the lookup result for "ones" somewhere while you do the lookup for "tens" (and, perhaps, "hundreds"). Storage could be...

  - ...an array. Be careful to check the numbers entered against the space in the array (so you don't overflow if someone enters too-large numbers). If you do it right, you do not need to store the *strings* you looked up, as you could store *pointers* to those strings.
  - ...a recursive function. (One that calls itself with the value divided by 10, then does the lookup for the "ones" of the value it was called with -- you get that via the modulo operator, `c % 10`.)

Comment: actually the assignment tasks me to do use those words (as based on calculator drawing) , by my mean is to replace each numbers with words just like qdbp means

Comment: @DickyGiancini: We've got quite some language barrier here; I am still not sure what the problem is. I guess, however, that my hints should still get you started.

Comment: sorry i'm not quite good in english so i cant explain better. i think my post already quite explains my problem, which is i wanted to print out the result from c=a+b as a words, example 24 = abged fbcg, or probably 66: fgcde fgcde . and about your hints i will learn it from now since im pretty much new to this C language

Comment: @DickyGiancini: As I said, it would be much clearer if the "words" your teacher gave you were the actual words "one", "two" etc.. Instead he obfuscated the assignment by using nonsensical letter sequences. I have a severe dislike for teachers like this. But the actual words do not matter for the way of how to get to them. Also, you should already have learned all the techniques necessary for this assignment; if you haven't, your teacher is even worse than just obfuscating...

Comment: okay as for now i will follow your solution. But what if we have to input beyond tens? probably thousands or hundred thousands? do we have to put it manually?

Comment: @DickyGiancini: As (apparently) you don't need different words for "tens" and "hundreds" and so on, you don't need anything special in your lookup function. See if `c > 10`. If yes, call yourself with `c / 10`. Get the "ones" value (`c % 10`). Look up and print the word. Return. The function will *recurse* as long as there are more digits, and the "deepest" call -- the one for the leftmost digit -- will print first. The stack (i.e. how "deep" function calls can be nested before running into memory problems) has *plenty* of room, a mere 64bit integer (having 20 digits max.) won't exhaust it.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here, you missed to use the `break` statement after each `case` statement.

Hence, yours is a [*fall-through* switch case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough), which is not what you want. It will jump to the case matching in `switch` statement and then fall-thorough all other available `case` statements.

---

Once you have solved that problem, one of the possible the approach to target the next problem is to explain it properly, with the current description, it's not very clear.

Comment: oh yeah i forgot about the break thing after each cases, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup for all the options of this word and then print the relevant according to the index without all the switch case mess

```
char* lookup = {
                {"abcdef\n"},
                {"bc\n"},
                {"abged\n"},
                {"abgcd\n"},
                {"fbgc\n"},
                {"afgod\n"},
                {"fgcde\n"},
                {"abc\n"},
                {"abcdefg\n"},
                {"abcdfg\n"},
};
```

then==>

```
c=a+b;
if (c>9)
{
printf("error\n");
}
else
{
printf(lookup[c]);
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont get what you mean, im a new to this language but it is already as my assignment

Comment: before i test back to my code, can i ask if you dont mind me what is lookup for? and what is the * used after char*?

Comment: you ask what is lookup in general or in this case? and char* is pointer to char, usually when you declare text inplace like that you use char* as read only data, you can't changed those values

Comment: oooh okay, i get the char* , also the lookup one is for this case

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you mean you want to print a string for each digit of a number, which is the result of whatever math function?

Try [untested]

```
int d = c;
do {
    switch (d % 10) { /* your replacement-text-switch goes here */ }
    d /= 10;
} while (d != 0)
```

This will print out the number in reverse.
If you want to print it out the other way, then you have to know about the maximum number you are going to calculate. (Or, being advanced you can use logarithm to determine the length of a number.)

Comment: i tested this one out, turns out it has become an infinite loop

Comment: hmm.. I don't know exactly where the infinity-loop comes from right now. For me it works. Maybe you post your updated code here.